# (Solved) Android Studio. TextView can't be found using FindViewByID of the specific textView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I'm attempting to implement a RecyclerView in my app that consists of multiple items, each have a button which transitions to another activity and a TextView which says where the button will go to. Here is the XML file for the design and code:
[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBDRr.png)
[XML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW2DQ.png)

This is my RecyclerView adapter.
[Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN4Yj.png)

When line 39 is called, I get a nullPointerException.
[Full Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU5N2.png)

The AndroidManifest file if it helps.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dbtW.png)

This happens when I open the activity that the RecyclerView is in. I have two System.out.println in my adapter to attempt to debug at the bottom of the adapter. The first one returned an integer for what I assume is the TextView ID, but the second one returns null. Why would it return null if the ID is an ID of something defined in R.id?

If it helps, I'm using this tutorial to learn about RecyclerView. If it's outdated that might explain it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mc0XT58A1Z4&t=1195s

I've searched the XML file of the layout for the item to make sure it exists, I've renamed the TextView to something completely random to make sure there were no duplicate naming issues. I've hardcoded the ID to the ID of the specific element of the RecyclerView row item. Each time, there's been no change. When I open the new activity I just want a single row to appear for the one element I've defined so far.

Comment: Don't link to code.  Post the code directly to this site.  And don't use images, use text for code (images are ok for showing how your app does/should work).

Comment: And findviewbyid can return null if nothing with that id exists under that parent, but the id itself exists (perhaps in another layout).  Common causes of that are typos, or inflating the wrong layout file.

Comment: In your case, is activity_scenario_pick the layout file of the recycler view element, or the activity?  It's named more like an activity layout

Comment: activity_scenario_pick is the layout file of the activity. The layout file for which the design and XML code is posted here are for the individual rows of the recyclerView, and it only has a layout file named recycler_row. This layout file is not defined in the Manifest. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I inflated the wrong layout. Thanks for the tip! It's solved now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.